# Why can't I addChild() in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

probably a really easy question but I've been trying to figure this out for a while...

I'm trying to add a child to the stage to represent the game score like so:

```
var gameScoreField:TextField = new TextField();
var gameScore:int = 0;

public function Game()
{
    // add score
    gameScoreField.text = "Score: " + gameScore;
    gameScoreField.embedFonts = true;
    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.font = "Tahoma";
    gameScoreField.setTextFormat(format);
    addChild(gameScoreField);
}
```

But when I run the game it isn't showing on the stage.  I have no errors and no warnings.

Why is this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you actually embed the Tahoma font? If not, set `embedFonts` to `false`.

Comment: Wow...that worked straight away.  Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Public courtesy to get this off of the unanswered list. Asker or answerer are welcome to post their own answer instead of accepting this one, if they want.*

**The asker needed to embed the Tahoma font, or set `embedFonts` to `false`.**